Introductory resources on rewriting logic
Hi I would like to grasp the theory behind Maude [1], [2]
Are there any recommended video lecture notes, talks or introductory notes?
I have been exposed to Functional Analysis, Topology and some Term Rewriting. But I am interested in getting into this fascinating field for formal verifications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to do my experiments in  Python or Julia or Golang (Python Software Engineering for Data Engineering is my main job). I am very open though regarding the programming language, especially if there is some code.
[1] https://maude.cs.illinois.edu/wiki/Rewriting_Logic
[2] https://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/papers/

Ok, from the downvoting, I get the spirit. I'm on my own. I'll do what I can with the Maude Book [1], [1] https://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/images/0/0d/Maude-book.pdf

I did not downvote, and I don't think this question fits the criteria for a downvote ("This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"), but I suspect you might be getting downvotes indicating as a proxy for a close vote that the voter feels that the question is inappropriate for MO.  (I find it a borderline case.)  There are communities on theoretical CS and proof assistants where this might (but I am not a regular in either one and don't know) find a better home.

Thank you very much @LSpice . I will head there and keep MathOverflow for my Combinatorics questions.

Now cross-posted on https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/ at Introductory resources on rewriting logic.
